# What happens when reading into a variable in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, pipeline, subshell

```
echo hello | read str
echo $str
```

This `read` is executed after the pipeline, which means that the output of the `echo` gets read into `str` - but because it is after a pipe, the contents of `str` are now in a subshell that cannot be read by the parent shell.

What happens in to the contents of `str`?  Does the pipe create a subshell, and then once the content are read into `str`, does the parent process kill the child process and `str` is erased - or does the contents of `str` live on somewhere outside the shell? Like how do we see what is in the subshells? Can we access subshells from the parent shells?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example, `$str` exists inside a subshell and by default, it disappears once the line has finished. A child process cannot modify its parent.

Aside from changing the shell option `lastpipe`, you can also change the code to avoid using a pipe. In this case, you could use:

```
read str < <(your command) 
# or
str=$(your command)
```

Both of these create subshells too, but `$str` is assigned to in the parent process.

Answer (score 12):

The value of `${str}` only exists during the lifetime of the subshell. Whether the left or right side of the pipe will be parent or subshell depends on the specific shell and the shell version.

Bash 4.x has an option `shopt -s lastpipe` to run the last command of a pipeline in the parent shell, like ksh93 does by default.  The value of `$str` will then persist.