# Filling dynamic array with user input value

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to create an array ,where the string x (as of now i am using static value for testing purpose) will be an input by the user during the run time.

````
#!/bin/bash
x="101:Redmi:Mobile:15000#102:Samsung:TV:20000#103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000#104:HP:Laptop:65000#105:Samsung:Mobile:10000#106:Samsung:TV:30000"
i=0
index=0 
declare -a categ_array=()
declare  -a amnt_array=()
declare -a cnt_array=()
echo "$x"  | tr '#' '\n' | cut -d ":" -f 3-4 | while read -r line ;
do
  echo "------Inside while loop------"
  echo $line
  category=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 1 )
  echo $category
  amount=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 2 )
  echo $amount
  echo $i
  categ_array[$i]=${category}
  amnt_array[$i]=${amount}
  cnt_array[$i]=1
  let i+=1
  
done

echo Category:
for n in "${categ_array[@]}"
do
 echo $n
done ```      



When I run the above script, I do not get any output. Where as I want output as

``` categ_array should have data as (Mobile,TV,Mobile,Laptop,Mobile,TV) ```                                 
```amnt_array should have data as (15000,20000,35000,65000,10000,30000)```




Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?
````

Comment: Updated the code and ran but still got no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the arrays are populated inside a pipeline.  Pipeline stages are run in sub-processes so changes to variables made within them are not visible in the main program.  See [What happens when reading into a variable in a pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46946888/4154375).

Since the arrays are populated in the last stage of the pipeline, you can fix the problem if you are running Bash version 4.2 or later by putting

```
shopt -s lastpipe
```

in the code before the pipeline.  That causes the last stage of the pipeline to be run in the top-level shell so changes to variables are visible after the pipeline completes.

Since you are using Bash, you can do what you want without using pipelines (or external commands like `tr` and `cut`).  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

x="101:Redmi:Mobile:15000#102:Samsung:TV:20000#103:OnePlus:Mobile:35000#104:HP:Laptop:65000#105:Samsung:Mobile:10000#106:Samsung:TV:30000"

declare -a categ_array=()
declare -a amnt_array=()
declare -a cnt_array=()

while IFS= read -r -d '#' line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    IFS=: read -r _ _ category amount <<<"$line"

    categ_array+=( "$category" )
    amnt_array+=( "$amount" )
    cnt_array+=( 1 )
done <<<"$x"

echo Category:
for n in "${categ_array[@]}"; do
    echo "$n"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much..it worked